# Number Theory Factor Challenge!!!

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

> For a positive integer $n$ let $P(n)$ denote the product of its positive divisors. E.g. $P(10)=1\times2\times5\times10=100$. Find all solutions to the equation $P(n)=15n^2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, format math on this site using LaTeX, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). There is also a [quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for the answers or have you posted it so you can answer this question ?

Comment: Looks like $n$ should be divisible by both $3$ and $5$ for they are factors of $P(n)$. What does that tell you about $n$?

Comment: Can you give an example of a solution?

Comment: Hint: show that if $n$ has $d$ divisors, $P(n)=n^{d/2}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer, I have also discovered that n has factors 5 and 3 but that's all I have managed to do. I'd appreciate it if anyone could please give me some advice or a hint,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divisors come in pairs. More precisely the divisors of a number $n$ that is not a perfect square come in pairs whose product is $n$, and a perfect square has one additional divisor, $\sqrt n$. In both cases, we get a factor $\sqrt n$ per divisor, so $P(n)=n^{\frac d2}$ if $n$ has $d$ divisors. Thus, in your question, $n^{\frac d2}=15n^2$, so $n^{\frac d2-2}=15$. Since $15$ is not a perfect power, you only have to check the values of $d$ with $0\lt\frac d2-2\le1$. Since neither $d=5$, $n=225$, nor $d=6$, $n=15$ works, the equation has no solutions.